# How to skip next class with numbers on css?

Tags: css

I have something like this and I need to skip first element "**comment-id-1**" to remove border-style on the next element "**border-style**". I tried to write, but it doesn't work.  Is there some regex rules for css? How can I do this?

> .comments-list:not(:first-child)

```
<div id="comments-list">
<ol class="comments-tree-listan">

<div id="comment-id-1">
    <div class="border-style">
        <div class="com_info">
         <span class="name">Fedor</span></div>

        <div class="text">
        <div id="comm-id-1"><p>Some text</p></div></div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="comment-id-2">
    <div class="border-style">
        <div class="com_info">
         <span class="name">Validim Puten</span></div>

        <div class="text">
        <div id="comm-id-2"><p>Text</p></div></div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="comment-id-3">...

</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` directly inside `<ol>` is semantically incorrect. You need to use `<li>`. But anyway, you can use this selector: `#comments-list ol > div:not(:first-child)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[id^="comment-id-"]` will give you all id start with the string.

`>` will get the immediate child after (only one level down)

```css
div[id^="comment-id-"]>.border-style {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="comments-list">
<ol class="comments-tree-listan">

<div id="comment-id-1">
    <div class="border-style">
        <div class="com_info">
         <span class="name">Fedor</span></div>

        <div class="text">
        <div id="comm-id-1"><p>Some text</p></div></div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="comment-id-2">
    <div class="border-style">
        <div class="com_info">
         <span class="name">Validim Puten</span></div>

        <div class="text">
        <div id="comm-id-2"><p>Text</p></div></div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="comment-id-3">...

</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Full code will be look like that: .border-style {
border-top: 1px solid red;
}

div[id^="comment-id-"]:first-child  > .border-style{
    border-style: none;
}